# Plotting odd complex functions w/o computer help

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am evaluating a complex integral that utilises the Cauchy Integral Formula and its properties.

In the book I'm reading, they give examples of evaluating integrals using CIT by graphing them, which really does help to see if points of a function is analytic in a certain domain.

For example, in evaluating this integral - how would I be able to plot the function shown in this integral, where C is a circle $|z|=1$ traversed once counter clockwise.  $$\int_{C}\frac{z+i}{z^3+2z^2}$$

Thanks.

Comment: You may be able to find ways of visualizing complex mappings but in general there is no way to plot the graph of a function from $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ analogously to graphs of functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (or up to 3-space). The point $(z, f(z))$ is in some sense a point of $\mathbb{R}^4$ which our brains find difficult to visualize...

Comment: I understand. This is something that I will come to terms with. I'm used to plotting basic real functions. Thanks for that. So in a case like this, how would one go about solving it? I understand that the integrand fails to be analytic point z = 0, but where to from there?

Comment: Indeed, it would be relatively straightforward to apply residue theorem (although probably tedious) but it appears your only given tool is Cauchy’s integral formula, correct? Just want to make sure before I offer a sketch of a solution.

Comment: Yes, sir. It's how they want us to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you only need to know where the function is singular

[image]

In your case it is at $z= 0$ and $z = -2$, but the second point is outside the region of integration, so we do not care about it

$$
\oint_C \frac{z + i}{z^2(z + 2)} {\rm d}z= \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z^2}{\rm d}z
$$

where the function

$$
f(z) = \frac{z + i}{z + 2}
$$

is well behaved in the region $|z| \leq 1$. The problem is at $z = 0$, where you have second order singularity, so you can use Cauchy's integral form

$$
\left.\frac{{\rm d}^n f}{{\rm d}z^n}\right|_{z = 0} = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z^{n + 1}}{\rm d}z
$$

with $n = 1$ which yields

$$
\oint_C\frac{z + i}{z^2(z + 2)} = 2 \pi i \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}z}\left(\frac{z + i}{z + 2}\right)_{z = 0} = 2\pi i \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{4} \right)
$$

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Better than the provided solutions!

Comment: Ah it looks like you beat me to it! Excellent visual too. Good to at least confirm by someone else's work that I can still recall this material correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch:** 
Note that the pole at $z=0$ has order $2$. Use the slightly generalized Cauchy formula for derivatives, 
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}z,$$
Write the original integrand as $g(z)$ and identify $f(z)$ from $g(z)=f(z)/z^2$ in your case for $n=1$ and $a=0$. Then compute the first derivative of $f$ at $a=0$ to compute the original integral (remember to multiply this by $2\pi i$). This yields $\pi (\frac12 +i)$.

Be sure to check all hypotheses of the Cauchy integral formula though to justify this rigorously, though (that $f$ is holomorphic inside the curve is required, not $g$, etc). Comment if you want some steps expanded, but preferably with where you got stuck also, or if you spot any typos, etc. It has been some time since I've gotten my hands dirty with contour integrals with only Cauchy's integral formula, however, [the example on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Example) is rather illustrative, though the poles there are only of order 1, unlike here.

Comment: Thank you. I genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you were working on an answer as well (+1)